# Positive Solution of Poisson Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Given the Poisson's equation

\begin{equation}
-\nabla^2 u = f \quad \mathrm{in} \ \Omega
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u=0 \quad \mathrm{on} \ \Gamma_D, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0 \quad \mathrm{on} \ \Gamma_N
\end{equation}

Is it possible to prove that if $f(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \Omega$ then $u(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \Omega$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as $\Gamma_D$ is not empty, then yes. To prove this, consider the perturbed problem
\begin{equation}
-\nabla^2 u_\varepsilon = f + \varepsilon \quad \mathrm{in} \ \Omega
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_\varepsilon=0 \quad \mathrm{on} \ \Gamma_D, \quad \frac{\partial u_\varepsilon}{\partial n} = \varepsilon \quad \mathrm{on} \ \Gamma_N
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon > 0$. Here $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian. Since $f\geq 0$, the Laplacian $\nabla^2 u_\varepsilon$ is strictly negative everywhere, and so $u_\varepsilon$ cannot have an interior minimum (since at any interior minimum, the Hessian would be nonnegative, and so the Laplacian---the trace of the Hessian--would also be nonnegative). Likewise, since the normal derivative is strictly positive, the minimum cannot occur on $\Gamma_N$. Hence, the minimum of $u_\varepsilon$ occurs on $\Gamma_D$, where $u_\varepsilon=0$. So $u_\varepsilon\geq0$. Then send $\varepsilon\to 0$, and use that $u_\varepsilon \to u$ uniformly.

Comment: By $\nabla^2$ I meant the Laplacian. Does the sign of the Laplacian allow to draw conclusions about the minima of $u_{\epsilon}$? Thanks.

Comment: @jlorenzo The Laplacian is the trece of the Hessian, and a necessary condition for a matrix to be strictly negative definite is that its trace is strictly negative. That being said, Jeff should've used different notations for the Laplacian and Hessian.

Comment: I copied your latex code, and didn't notice the notation. And you're right, I should have said Laplacian, not Hessian. I corrected the answer.

Comment: I was wondering if the same reasoning would apply if we also have the following boundary condition besides the ones already mentioned:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{n}} + \alpha u = 0, \quad \alpha > 0 \quad \mathrm{on} \quad \Gamma_R 
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $\Gamma_R$?

Comment: An additional subset of the domain boundary such that $\Gamma = \Gamma_D \cup \Gamma_N \cup \Gamma_R$

Comment: Yes, the same reasoning applies when $a>0$. If the minimum of $u$ occurs at some $x\in \Gamma_R$, then the normal derivative is non-positive at $x$, and so $au(x) \geq 0$. Since $a>0$ we get $u(x)\geq 0$ at the minimum $x$, so $u\geq 0$.

Comment: It is interesting to see that positivity of the solition can only be ensured if $a>0$. Thank you.